# MySQL: How to display the tuple with minimum value of an attribute?

Tags: mysql, function

I have created a table Books with the following attributes:
**Books**(*BookID, BookName, Author, Price*)

Now I wish to find the name of the book which has the least price(cheapest book's name), along with its price.

To do so, I did something like:

```
SELECT min(Price) FROM Books;
```

This gave me the minimum price ($55.36). And then I used:

```
SELECT BookName,Price FROM Books 
WHERE Price=55.36;
```

This gave me the answer I was looking for...

But I want to ask, is there a *better way*, so that I don't need to know the minimum price before finding the answer?Can I do it in a single query?

I tried something like:

```
SELECT BookName,Price FROM Books
WHERE Price=min(Price);
```

But I got an Invalid use of Group function error. Any help would be appreciated.
I am using MySQL Server version 8.0.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the question to which it is marked duplicate for

Answer (score 1):

In a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), you can determine the minimum price value out of all the books. Now, you can join this result-set back to the main table `Books` on minimum Price value, to get the row having lowest price.

```
SELECT b1.BookName, 
       b1.Price 
FROM Books AS b1 
JOIN (SELECT MIN(b2.Price) AS min_price 
      FROM Books AS b2
     ) AS dt ON dt.min_price = b1.Price
```

---

Another alternative approach is using a [Subquery](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/). In a subquery, determine the minimum price value, and use `WHERE .. IN(..)` to determine the rows having lowest price value:

```
SELECT b1.BookName, 
       b1.Price 
FROM Books AS b1 
WHERE b1.Price IN (SELECT MIN(b2.Price)
                   FROM Books AS b2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you tell me what's wrong with the Price=min(Price)?

Comment: @ASuresh you cannot use aggregation functions like that